# Finding extents of Oracle BIN$ segments

Tags: oracle, shrink, flashback

I am looking for information on recyclebin extents.

When dropping a table its segments are renamed to 'BIN$...' system generated names and the extents are hidden.

Will those extents still stop me from shrinking a data file (or tablespace)? If so I would like to account for them in the script.

Currently I am using a query inspired by AskTom's maxshrink.sql:

```
select tbs.TABLESPACE_NAME, df.FILE_NAME,
    round(MAX(e.BLOCKS+e.BLOCK_ID+1)*tbs.BLOCK_SIZE/1024/1024,2) "MinMB",
    round(MAX(df.BYTES)/1024/1024,2) "FileMB"
  from DBA_TABLESPACES tbs
  LEFT JOIN DBA_DATA_FILES df on tbs.TABLESPACE_NAME = df.TABLESPACE_NAME
  LEFT JOIN DBA_EXTENTS e on df.FILE_ID = e.FILE_ID AND df.RELATIVE_FNO = e.RELATIVE_FNO
  -- WHERE
  --   tbs.TABLESPACE_NAME like 'MY%'
  GROUP BY df.FILE_ID, df.RELATIVE_FNO, tbs.TABLESPACE_NAME, tbs.BLOCK_SIZE, df.FILE_NAME
  ORDER BY 1,2;
```

*Update*: Initially my question also asked why I no longer see the 'BIN$' segments created by Flashback Drop Table anymore in 12.2 anymore. However that was an error on my side, my test tables had simply no segments to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table bp.t1 as select * from dba_users;
drop table bp.t1;

select owner, object_name, original_name from dba_recyclebin where owner = 'BP';

OWNER OBJECT_NAME                     ORIGINAL_NAME
----- ------------------------------- -------------
BP    BIN$XY0E/EKVFyXgU0cBqMCr3Q==$0  T1           

select * from dba_extents where owner = 'BP';

no rows selected
```

Removing (commenting out) the filter from the relevant part of the definition of `DBA_EXTENTS` that filters dropped objects:

```
select
  ds.owner, ds.segment_name, ds.partition_name, ds.segment_type,
  ds.tablespace_name,
  e.ktfbueextno, f.file#, e.ktfbuebno,
  e.ktfbueblks * ds.blocksize, e.ktfbueblks, e.ktfbuefno
from
  sys.sys_dba_segs ds, sys.x$ktfbue e, sys.file$ f
where
  e.ktfbuesegfno = ds.relative_fno
  and e.ktfbuesegbno = ds.header_block
  and e.ktfbuesegtsn = ds.tablespace_id
  and ds.tablespace_id = f.ts#
  and e.ktfbuefno = f.relfile#
  and bitand(NVL(ds.segment_flags, 0), 1) = 1
  --and bitand(NVL(ds.segment_flags,0), 65536) = 0
  and ds.owner = 'BP';

OWNER SEGMENT_NAME                   PARTITION_NAME SEGMENT_TYPE       TABLESPACE_NAME KTFBUEEXTNO      FILE#  KTFBUEBNO E.KTFBUEBLKS*DS.BLOCKSIZE KTFBUEBLKS  KTFBUEFNO
----- ------------------------------ -------------- ------------------ --------------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ------------------------- ---------- ----------
BP    BIN$XY0E/EKVFyXgU0cBqMCr3Q==$0                TABLE              USERS                     0          4        128                     65536          8          4
```

Comment: Ah that might be a hint (however I haven’t seen them in sys_dba_segs when I glanced over it, will test that later.

Comment: @eckes Seen what? Extent information comes from `X$KTFBUE`, not `SYS_DBA_SEGS`. It is just the `segment_flags` in `SYS_DBA_SEGS` that prevents extent information appearing in `DBA_EXTENTS`.

Comment: The BIN$ segments.

Comment: @eckes First check the value of the parameter `recyclebin`. Simplest explanation is that is set to `off`.

Comment: I think I found the problem, the tables I had dropped have been empty Test tables and it seems they had no initial segment, so that’s why they showed up in the recyclebin but not the dba_segments.

Comment: @eckes That is called deferred segment creation and while it is related, extents of dropped segments still do not show up in `DBA_EXTENTS` because of the above filter.

Answer (score 2):

> Do you know since when those segments are hidden(?), and is there a way to actually find their extents?

You can find their details from `*_SEGMENTS` views/synonyms.

```
SQL> select bytes from user_segments where segment_name='BIN$XYbYSYopQFTgUzIUqMA4vA==$0';

     BYTES
----------
     65536
```

> Will those extents still stop me from shrinking a data file (or tablespace)?

Yes, they may stop you to shrink the data files. Dropped tables and any associated objects such as indexes, constraints, nested tables, and other dependent objects are not moved, they are simply renamed with a prefix of `BIN$`.

Consider the following(it's just for demonstration purpose only) example.

```
SQL> conn sys@orclpdb as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> create tablespace tbs1 datafile size 1M;

Tablespace created.

SQL> alter user jay quota unlimited on tbs1;

User altered.

SQL> create table t1(id number, col1 varchar2(100)) tablespace tbs1;

Table created.

SQL> insert into t1 select level, 'dsfldshfkjdhsfkdshfdklsjfhdkhfdks'||level 
     from dual connect by level<=1000;

1000 rows created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select bytes from user_segments where segment_name='T1';

     BYTES
----------
    983040

SQL> conn sys@orclpdb as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.

SQL> select ts#, name from v$tablespace;

       TS# NAME
---------- ------------------------------
        10 TBS1

1 rows selected.

SQL> select bytes from v$datafile where ts#=10;

     BYTES
----------
   1048576

SQL> select file# from v$datafile where ts#=10;

     FILE#
----------
        55

SQL> conn jay@orclpdb
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> drop table t1;

Table dropped.

SQL> select object_name from recyclebin;

OBJECT_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BIN$XYY3afBNKwPgUzIUqMAIkA==$0
BIN$XYYmdj0XKLjgUzIUqMB2iA==$0

SQL> conn sys@orclpdb as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> alter database datafile 55 resize 512K;
alter database datafile 55 resize 512K
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-03297: file contains used data beyond requested RESIZE value

SQL> conn jay@orclpdb
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> purge recyclebin;

Recyclebin purged.

SQL> conn sys@orclpdb as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> alter database datafile 55 resize 512K;

Database altered.
```

> Hm, on my 12.2 system I see no BIN$ segments in *_SEGMENTS views (with SYS as SYSDBA user). And I think they never showed up in *_EXTENTS, or?

There is no recycle bin for SYSDBA privilege.

> Each user can be thought of as having his own recycle bin, since unless a user has the SYSDBA privilege, the only objects that the user has access to in the recycle bin are those that the user owns. 
>   [What is Recycle Bin?](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables011.htm#ADMIN11679)

Comment: Hm, on my 12.2 system I see no BIN$ segments in *_SEGMENTS views (with SYS as SYSDBA user). And I think they never showed up in *_EXTENTS, or?

Comment: Yes, they don't show up in `*_EXTENTS` regardless of privilege. However, I can get the segment details of `BIN$' segments from `USER_SEGMENTS`.

Comment: @JSapkota Only from USER_SEGMENTS? Or from DBA_SEGMENTS, too?

Comment: @miracle173: Yeah, from both.

Comment: Did you test it in 12.2? With or without CDB?

Comment: @ecked, I tested that on a PDB under a 12.2  CDB.

Comment: Found my segments (or actually I did not find them:) - adjusted question.